# Share screen with multiple users

Tags: skype, screen-sharing

I am currently using Skype to share my screen with a single person.

Is there a away to share your screen with more then a single user?
It would be nice if it was via skype but this is not mandatory.

I prefer a free service if possible.

Comment: The answer promoting RHUB was downvoted because it was, essentially, spam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/hi/download/currentversion.aspx) is a great, free option. It has drag & drop support for files, supports multi-monitor setups, integrated screenshots and allows you to record your sessions as well. There is also a meeting mode which allows upto 25 participants. Plus, it has [iOS](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/teamviewer/id482946817) and [Android](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.teamviewer.meeting.market.mobile) apps to enable access on the go. You can view the 'Getting Started' guide [here](http://www.teamviewer.com/hi/help/firststeps.aspx).

Alternatively, if you are looking for a browser-based solution or are in a hurry, you can try [Join.me](http://join.me/) or [Yuuguu](http://www.yuuguu.com/s/home).

Comment: The link to YuuGuu does not work. According to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuuguu the company was acquired by PowWowNow: https://www.powwownow.co.uk/

Answer (score 1):

Check out [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx), it allows multiple participants and is very easy to set up - no installation needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try-

Mikogo (Free - http://www.mikogo.com/ )

or

GotoMeeting (30 Day Trial - http://www.gotomeeting.com/fec/ )